# Vue.js with iView Table - accessing Elasticsearch search response object

Tags: vue.js, iview

I am using the iView UI kit table in my Vue.js application that consumes an Elasticsearch API with axios. My problem is that I just can't seem to get to access the nested search response object, which is an array list object. I only get to access the 1st level fields, but not the nested ones. I don't know how to set the table row key in the iView table.

This is how my axios call and mapper methods look like:

```
listObjects(pageNumber){
      const self = this
      self.$Loading.start()
      self.axios.get("/api/elasticsearch/")
        .then(response => {
          self.ajaxTableData = self.mapObjectToArray(response.data);
          self.dataCount = self.ajaxTableData.length;

          if(self.ajaxTableData.length < self.pageSize){
            self.tableData = self.ajaxTableData;
          } else {
            self.tableData = self.ajaxTableData.slice(0,self.pageSize);
          }
          self.$Loading.finish()
        })
        .catch(e => {
          self.tableData = []
          self.$Loading.error()
          self.errors.push(e)
        })
    },
    mapObjectToArray(data){
      var mappedData = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
        return data[key];
      })
      return mappedData
    },
```

The iView table columns look like this:

```
tableColumns: [
        {
          title: 'Study Date',
          key: 'patientStudy.studyDate',
          width: 140,
          sortable: true,
          sortType: 'desc'
        },
        {
          title: 'Modality',
          key: "generalSeries.modality",
          width: 140,
          sortable: true
        },
        ...
    ]
```

The (raw) Elasticsearch documents look like this:

```
[
{ "score":1, "id":"3a710fa2c1b3f6125fc168c9308531b59e21d6b3", 
"type":"dicom", "nestedIdentity":null, "version":-1, "fields":{
  "highlightFields":{

  },
  "sortValues":[

  ],
  "matchedQueries":[

  ],
  "explanation":null,
  "shard":null,
  "index":"dicomdata",
  "clusterAlias":null,
  "sourceAsMap":{
     "generalSeries":[
        {
           "seriesInstanceUid":"999.999.2.19960619.163000.1",
           "modality":"MR",
           "studyInstanceUid":"999.999.2.19960619.163000",
           "seriesNumber":"1"
        }
     ],
     "patientStudy":[
        {
           "studyDate":"19990608"
        }
     ]
  }
```

}
]

And this is how the consumed object looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the fields I need to access are within the "sourceAsMap" object, and then nested in arrays. 
How can I provide the iView table cell key to access them?

**UPDATE:**
I now "remapped" my Elasticsearch object before displaying it in the Vue.js table, and it works now. However, I don't think that the way I did it is very elegant or clean....maybe you can help me to do it in a better way. This is my method to remap the object:

```
getData(data){
  let jsonMapped = []
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    let id = {}
    id['id'] = data[i].id
    let generalData = data[i]['sourceAsMap']['generalData'][0]
    let generalSeries = data[i]['sourceAsMap']['generalSeries'][0]
    let generalImage = data[i]['sourceAsMap']['generalImage'][0]
    let generalEquipment = data[i]['sourceAsMap']['generalEquipment'][0]
    let patient = data[i]['sourceAsMap']['patient'][0]
    let patientStudy = data[i]['sourceAsMap']['patientStudy'][0]
    let contrastBolus = data[i]['sourceAsMap']['contrastBolus'][0]
    let specimen = data[i]['sourceAsMap']['specimen'][0]
    jsonMapped[i] = Object.assign({}, id, generalData, generalSeries, generalImage, generalEquipment, patient,
    patientStudy, contrastBolus, specimen)
  }
  return jsonMapped
},
```

The result is this:

[image]

Even though it now works, but how can I optimize this code?

Comment: Does every key contain an array with one object or more? If one you can transform your response and avoid single element arrays.

Comment: Each array contains only one element (object). How would I do such a transform?

Answer (score 0):

A few functions can help you with your situation

```
let data = [{
    key1: ['k1'],
    key2: ['k2'],
    key3: [{
        subKey1: 'sk1',
        subKey2: ['sk2'],
        subObject: [{ name: 'John', surname: 'Doe' }],
        items: [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
    }]
}];
function mapIt(data) {
    if (isSingletonArray(data)) {
       data = data[0];
    }
    for(const key in data) {
        if (isSingletonArray(data[key])) {
            data[key] = mapIt(data[key][0]);
        } else {
            data[key] = data[key];
        }
    }
    return data;
}
function isSingletonArray(obj) {
    return typeof obj === 'object' && Array.isArray(obj) && obj.length === 1;
}
console.log(mapIt(data));
```

Outputs:

```
{ 
    key1: 'k1',
    key2: 'k2',
    key3: { 
        subKey1: 'sk1',
        subKey2: 'sk2',
        subObject: { name: 'John', surname: 'Doe' },
        items: [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 7 ] 
    } 
}
```

You can check it in your browser. `mapIt` unwraps the singleton arrays into objects or primitives.
But I recommend you to watch out special elastic client libraries for javascript. It could save you from writing extra code.

Comment: Lev, thank you for trying to help, but for some reason, this doesn't work. I think this has something to do with the UI Kit that doesn't support nested objects for the table cell keys. I am not sure how to get this to work...Any other ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Then maybe it's better to create flat object with fields you want place into the table. `tableData = { studyDate: data.patientStudy.studyDate, modality: data.generalSeries.modality }` and `key`s in your table column config will be looks like `{ key: 'studyDate' }`